# How can i disable "Scroll Inactive Windows" in windows 10 only for my programm (c#, winform)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, scroll

I have a Panel in my form which should always be scrolled by the MouseWheel, at any mouse position in my form (even in a Multiline-TextBox with ScrollBars). In Windows 7 i could already achieve this by having a MouseWheel-event called from every TextBox,Combobox and TreeView. The Event will always set the focus to the Panel.

But in Windows 10, i will get stuck on every Multiline-TextBox inside of the Panel. It seems like the "Scroll Inactive Windows"-Option (inside the mouse options of windows) is the cause for this, as it will set the focus to the TextBox on which the mouse is hovering over.

The executable will be started from a batch file. So it is possible to disable the optione for the windows user by edditing the regestry (https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/2435/windows-10-tip-scroll-inactive-windows) but this is a horrible solution.

Is there a way to disable "Scroll Inactive Windows" just for this Window?

Comment: So how are you gonna scroll those other controls if they need scrolling?

Comment: By the scrollbar (with the mouse and without mousewheel)